# What is the best way to only insert new values into a sqlite database with python?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

I am building a database from scraped data. I want to only insert records which are not yet in my database and disregard all the duplicate records.

Following is my code

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Database.db')
df.to_sql("My_cool_data_Temp", conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
query = "SELECT * FROM My_cool_data_Temp EXCEPT SELECT * FROM My_cool_data;"        
new_entries = pd.read_sql(query, conn)               
new_entries.to_sql("My_cool_data", conn, if_exists='append', index=False)       
conn.execute("DROP TABLE My_cool_data_Temp;")
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed:
```

Printing out `new_entries` I saw that for some reason the query doesn't seem to work as I get duplicates.

Any ideas what I might miss? I would be also glad for different approaches to my problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Post the table definitions and sample data to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing sample data, issue may be unique identifiers on all records. If so, avoid [**`SELECT * FROM`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/1422451) and instead explicitly define *all* columns. Otherwise, any unique identifier will not match to existing records and consequently cause all records in first select to return in `EXCEPT`. Also, use an insert-select and avoid second pandas call:

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect('Database.db')

df.to_sql("My_cool_data_Temp", conn, if_exists='replace', index=False) 

query = """INSERT INTO My_cool_data (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...)
           SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ...
           FROM My_cool_data_Temp
           EXCEPT 
           SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ...
           FROM My_cool_data;
        """
conn.execute(query)

conn.execute("DROP TABLE My_cool_data_Temp")
conn.commit()
```

If columns are so many (which may be indicative of sub-optimal database design), build SQL with `DataFrame.columns` (removing unique identifiers). Backticks added for reserved words or column names with special characters and/or spaces.

```py
df = df.drop(["unique_id_column"], axis="columns")

cols = "`, `".join(df.columns.tolist())

query = f"""INSERT INTO My_cool_data (`{cols}`)
            SELECT `{cols}`
            FROM My_cool_data_Temp
            EXCEPT 
            SELECT `{cols}`
            FROM My_cool_data;
         """
```